# Putting a string or int back on the front of cin

Tags: c++, input

I have a problem where I get an int as input at the wrong time in my c++ program, so I need to "put it back" on cin later.  However the closest thing I can find to do this is the pushback function for istreams.  This sadly is only for characters and using multiple characters seems to separate them.  Is there a good way to put a piece of input back on the front of cin? Thanks.

**edit**

The reason for this is that I am using a graph class that uses the >> operator for input, but the first piece of input has to be the number of edges.  I was hoping to leave the graph class alone and just give cin the number of edges myself.  So basically the only piece of input that is out of order is the first int that gets sent from cin.

Comment: Could you explain what you're doing a little better? It's hard to imagine a case where you would have to push things back into the stream once you've collected them, especially if it's just an ordering error. There's probably a smarter solution.

Comment: Is it hard-coded to `cin` or do you have a chance of using another stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a seekable input (such as a file), you can use [seekg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/seekg/).  Unfortunately, this won't work for non-seekable streams (such as a pipe or human input).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just 'keep' the int till you you've finished the next read from cin and then tack it on the front of the read string instead of trying to force it back into the buffer? Just a thought...

Answer (score 0):

Along with the comment, I'd add that you could create a wrapper or helper for the class that accepts input in the order you like it.